# populate a field when referencing a node

Tags: rules, nodes

I am using the node reference module.

When referencing a node, I want to populate a text field in the new node, with the value of a text field from the referenced node.

Can this be done by a rule?

Can anyone confirm the rule?

Many thanks

David

added comments below

Comment: question is a little unclear - do you want to populate a field in the node being referenced, or the node doing the reference? as well - do you want it to happen imediately, or upon saving the node?

Comment: Following on from Geoff. You probably don't need to be populating that field at all as the node will always be referenced and you can use Views to display that field. Also--you don't mention whether you are using Drupal 7. If so you should really be using the entityreference module instead.

Comment: Geoff, thanks for your reply - i want it in the new node which will be the node doing the referencing? when saving the node will be fine. many thanks. david

Comment: queenvictoria, thanks for your reply. the reason i need to include the field on the new node is because i want to use it as part on the URL and have it available as a token. i also need the token available for a metatag. many thanks. david

Comment: @user30505 No need to reask the question.  If someone knows the answer, they will help you out.  I am closing this one, as the other has more details in it.